# Как задать background color в теме стиля на android?

Tags: java, android, android-style

Как задать background color при нажатии на элемент в теме стиля на android? Надо сделать чтобы это работало для всего приложения.
Перепробовал кучу параметров не получается никак.

Answer (score 1):

У меня не получилось выставить бэкгр нажатия всех элементов в styles.xml пришлось выставлять для каждого элемента или активности отдельно в ее layout файле для этого создал вот такие файлы в drawable присвоив их элементам в layout (android:background="@drawable/st_background_btn"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Для actionBar у меня все же получилось выставить в styles.xml в тему такой итем который менял бы бэкграунд нажатия значка:

```
 <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/st_background</item>
```

Для TabHost табов пришлось сделать отдельные layout и там задать им background

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно - стиль - статический файл, он упаковывается вместе с остальными ресурсами на этапе компиляции и его невозможно изменить в рантайме.

У вас 2 выхода:

1. Создать несколько тем с разными цветами, жестко заданными заранее. В нужный момент сохранить куда-то какую тему надо отображать и пересоздать все активити. В `onCreate` каждой активити задать стиль, взятый на основе созранённого ранее значения. Например цифры/строки в БД/SharedPreferences
2. Не использовать стили. Просто хранить где-то нужный цвет и в ручную задавать его всем нужным элементам в нужный момент

Comment: Нет вы наверно меня не поняли мне не надо все в рантайме менять, мне просто стандартная тема не нажатия эл-тов не нравиться, поменять не могу. Короче я решил обходными пятями решил, напишу ответ.